# Choosing all possible combinations for pairing the elements of two vectors in R

Tags: r, combinatorics

I have a problem that is hard for me to grasp mathematically. So hopefully I can get across what I want to do with this simplified example:

Assume that I have to vectors of the length n = 3.

```
a <- 1:3
b <- 1:3
```

I want to know how often I am able to draw three elements of a and elements of b without replacements and pair them, where the order is irrelevant, and get a unique set. A pair of (1 2) is not same as (2 1), but I don't want to have something like this

1 2

2 1

1 3,

becuse I don't want that any element (column-wise) to repeate. In the example, the 1 however appears twice in the first column.

Two sets of valid parings would be

1 1

2 2

3 3

or

1 3

2 2

3 1.

I already figured out it is not n*n choose k, which would be 84 as in an Unordered Sampling without Replacement problem.

The end aim is to calculate the number of uniques pairs of 20 combinations from two vectors with length of n = 20.

Comment: The example was chosen just to make clear what I mean. Because I draw without replacement I should not get a result like that example.

Comment: I added example which are vaild. There are more than 3 as 1 2; 2 3; 3 1 and 1 2;  2 1; 3 3 are valid as well.

Comment: But this would include invalid parings such as 1 2; 2 1; 1 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start with something even simpler like two vectors `1,2` then the combinations are `2! = 2`, because `1` can be matched with any of `1,2` (2 choices) and `2` will definitely get whatever remains (0 choices) like

```
1 1 | 1 2
2 2 | 2 1
```

If you consider two vectors `1,2,3` then the combinations are `3! = 3*2 = 6`, because 1 can be matched with any of `1,2,3` (3 options), then `2` can be matched with any of the 2 remaining numbers (2 options on top of that) and then `3` will definitely get whatever remains (0 choices) like:

```
1 1 | 1 1 | 1 2 | 1 2 | 1 3 | 1 3
2 2 | 2 3 | 2 1 | 2 3 | 2 2 | 2 1
3 3 | 3 2 | 3 3 | 3 1 | 3 1 | 3 2
```

So for two vectors of `1,2,3,...,20` you'll get 20! options.

Comment: From comments `But this would include invalid parings such as 1 2; 2 1; 1 3`, I thought he was after unique pairs. I do seem to have misunderstood something.

Comment: He says "valid pairings" and then he has both 1,3 and 3,1. I thin the whole point is not to have the same number in the same column, because he can't chose the same number from a given vector multiple times....

Comment: Thanks a lot and my apologies if I was not clear enough.